# Bash - replace string inside all files in directory

Tags: bash, replace, text-files, batch-processing

I have 31 .ctl files in a directory, they looks like this:

```
load data CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8  
infile '../dane/kontakty_Biura_wyborcze.csv' "str '\n'"
append
into table ODI_PUW_OSOBY2
fields terminated by ';'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           ( LP CHAR(4000),
             WOJEWODZTWO CHAR(4000),
             POWIAT CHAR(4000),
             GMINA CHAR(4000),
             NAZWA_INSTYTUCJI CHAR(4000),
             KOD CHAR(4000),
             MIEJSCOWOSC CHAR(4000),
             ADRES CHAR(4000),
             NAZWISKO_I_IMIE CHAR(4000),
             FUNKCJA CHAR(4000),
             TEL_SLUZB_STACJON_1 CHAR(4000),
             TEL_SLUZB_STACJON_2 CHAR(4000),
             TEL_SLUZB_STACJON_3 CHAR(4000),
             TEL_SLUZB_KOM_1 CHAR(4000),
             TEL_SLUZB_KOM_2 CHAR(4000),
             FAX_SLUZB_1 CHAR(4000),
             FAX_SLUZB_2 CHAR(4000),
             EMAIL_SLUZB_1 CHAR(4000),
             EMAIL_SLUZB_2 CHAR(4000),
             WWW CHAR(4000),
             TYP CONSTANT "Biura wyborcze.",
             ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT "20130717144702"
             ODI_STATUS CONSTANT "0",
             IMIE EXPRESSION     "pg_odi_utils.zwroc_imiona(pg_odi_utils.usun_przyrostki(:NAZWISKO_I_IMIE),0)",
             NAZWISKO EXPRESSION "pg_odi_utils.zwroc_nazwisko(pg_odi_utils.usun_przyrostki(:NAZWISKO_I_IMIE),0)"
       )
```

There are 31 files like this. I need to replace value in this line:

```
ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT '20130717144702'
```

to new timestamp, the same for all files. Current timestamp is not known (I mean value that exists in file currently, in this case '20130717144702').

So I need to (for each file found in directory):

- find line starting from ODI_SESJA_ID
- replace value after 'ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT ' with new one
- the rest lines in file should stay untouched

What is the best way to do this using bash? Should I use sed or similar tools? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
sed 's/\(^[ \t]\+ODI_SESJA_ID\ CONSTANT\).*/\1 \"newtimestamp\"/' tmp
```

should work.

Group the string that will be retained, adding the placeholder (`\1`) in the replacement string. Replace `newtimestamp` with whatever value you prefer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using sed like so:

```
sed -i "/^[ \t]*ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT/s/'[^']\+'/'REPLACEMENT'/" *.ctl
```

The -i flag to sed means it modifies the files in place, so I usually try it on a single file first with the -e flag instead of the -i flag and confirm that sed's output is what I was looking for.

Explanation:

1. The double-quotes protect my regex from the shell.
2. `/^[ \t]*ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT/` matches only the lines that start with whitespace followed by 'ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT'.
3. `s/'[^']\+'/'REPLACEMENT'/` substitutes 'REPLACEMENT' (quoted) for the first quoted portion of the text on matching lines.

The document at http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt (top Google hit for 'sed one liners' is pretty helpful for quickly dispatching these sort of tasks.

Comment: Not working for me... no error but no effect as well, files seems to be untouched

Answer (score 0):

I found some simplest solution, it seems to be good:

```
sed -i 's/.*ODI_SESJA_ID.*/             ODI_SESJA_ID CONSTANT "'$(date +%s)'",/' *.ctl
```

It replaces lines that contains ODI_SESJA_ID to new value. Not very elegant, because it replaces entire line, instead of only value that need to be processed.